# ArrayStoreException when using toArray

Tags: android, arraylist

This code throws an `ArrayStoreException`. Don't know that is wrong with it.

```
hm = new HighscoreManager();             
hm.addScore(Game.timePerWord);      
String[] converted = new String[hm.scores.size()];
converted = hm.scores.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: What is the type of HighscoreManager.scores?

Comment: Which line throws the exception? The last one?

Comment: HighscoreManager.scores is a String and the last line throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayStoreException` occurs with a type mismatch in the collection and the array as we can see [in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html).  Maybe they are both not java.lang.String?